# a function defined as an integral can be continued analytically

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following question:

Verify that the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \, \frac{t^{z}}{e^{\,t\,}+1}dt$ represents an analytic function in the half plane $Re(z)>-1$. Show also that this function can be continued analytically to the strip $Re(z)>-2$ except for the point $-1$ and the point $-1$ is a first order pole of this function, find the residue at this point.

We have

$|\frac{t^{z}}{e^t+1}|\leq\frac{t^{Re(z)}}{2}$ for $t>0$ but the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{Re(z)}}{2}dt$

is not convergent. I don't know how to approach otherwise. Any help would be great.

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{t^n}{e^t+1}~dt~=~n!~\eta(n+1),~$ and $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{t^n}{e^t-1}~dt~=~n!~\zeta(n+1),~$ see the [Dirichlet $\eta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) and [Riemann $\zeta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) functions for more information, both of which possess well-known analytic continuations.